# Encoding and decoding

Tags: text, compression, encode, decode

I am looking to encode some text that could be 1 charchter long or or 10,000 or infinite
and decode (reverse the algorithm).

I am looking something like MD5 on PHP, but reversable, as MD5 is one way.

This could be server side or JavaScript. If both, then it's even better.

Comment: What's the purpose of encoding and decoding the text? Do you want to encrypt it for safety, do you want to compress it or do you have another reason?

Comment: compress would be your answer :)

Comment: md5 five is one way because its a Hash algorithm. What you're looking for is an encryption algorithm like DES or Triple DES

Edit:
If compression is your need, then go for GZip

Comment: gzip would compress it as a file like or would it return a string containing a key to decompress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For compression**

In Javascript, http://rumkin.com/tools/compression/compress_huff.php

Also have a look at [javascript text compression/decompression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994667/javascript-text-compression-decompression)

**For encryption**

In PHP, you can use mcrypt:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php

Sample code (from above site):

```
<?php
class Cipher {
    private $securekey, $iv;
    function __construct($textkey) {
        $this->securekey = hash('sha256',$textkey,TRUE);
        $this->iv = mcrypt_create_iv(32);
    }
    function encrypt($input) {
        return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->securekey, $input, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $this->iv));
    }
    function decrypt($input) {
        return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->securekey, base64_decode($input), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $this->iv));
    }
}

$cipher = new Cipher('secret passphrase');

$encryptedtext = $cipher->encrypt("hide me");
echo "->encrypt = $encryptedtext<br />";

$decryptedtext = $cipher->decrypt($encryptedtext);
echo "->decrypt = $decryptedtext<br />";

var_dump($cipher);
?>
```

Comment: The OP clarified that s?he doesn't want encryption, but compression.

Comment: Oh. Question has changed completely.

Comment: sorry mate but this compression is rather silly if there is 3050 characters on the string to be encrypted, you end up with 5000+ characters therefore it is not making it smaller in size... infact it makes it larger.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compress string, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294297/javascript-implementation-of-gzip) for info on JavaScript implementation of LZW, Huffman, LZ77 and others. I'm pretty sure that there are similar libraries in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There are implementations of rot13 for [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php) and [JS](http://tornio.info/rot13.html), as well as URL encoding ([PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), [JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURI)).

Comment: but isn't rot13 and the like, obsolete

Comment: Obsolete? No. They do perfectly well for the things they have been used for for the past century.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
class ed2
{

BufferedReader obj = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

void encode()throws InterruptedException,IOException
{
    String rs,ren;

    encoder_symbol();
    rs = encode_input();
    ren = encode_find(rs);
    encode_display(ren);
}

void decode()throws InterruptedException,IOException
{
    String rs,rde;

    decoder_symbol();
    rs = decode_input();
    rde = decode_find(rs);
    decode_display(rde);
}

void encoder_symbol()throws InterruptedException //just for fun
{
    System.out.println("********  ***         ***  *********  ************  ******      ********  *****");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("********  ****        ***  *********  ************  ********    ********  *** **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("***       *****       ***  ***        ***      ***  ***   ***   ***       ***  **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("***       *** **      ***  ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ***       *** **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("******    ***  **     ***  ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ******    *****");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("******    ***   **    ***  ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ******    *****");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("***       ***     **  ***  ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ***       *** **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("***       ***      ** ***  ***        ***      ***  ***   ***   ***       ***  **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("*******   ***       *****  *********  ************  ********    ********  ***   **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("*******   ***        ****  *********  ************  ******      ********  ***    **");
    Thread.sleep(2700);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
}

void decoder_symbol()throws InterruptedException // just for fun
{
    System.out.println("******      ********  *********  ************  ******      ********  *****");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("********    ********  *********  ************  ********    ********  *** **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("***   ***   ***       ***        ***      ***  ***   ***   ***       ***  **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("***    ***  ***       ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ***       *** **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("***    ***  ******    ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ******    *****");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("***    ***  ******    ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ******    *****");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("***    ***  ***       ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ***       *** **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("***   ***   ***       ***        ***      ***  ***   ***   ***       ***  **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("********    ********  *********  ************  ********    ********  ***   **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("******      ********  *********  ************  ******      ********  ***    **");
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
}

String encode_input()throws IOException
{
    String s;
    System.out.println("ENTER THE STRING TO BE ENCODED");
    s = obj.readLine();
    return(s);
}

String decode_input()throws IOException
{
    String s;
    System.out.println("ENTER THE CODE TO BE DECODED");
    s = obj.readLine();
    return(s);
}

String encode_find(String s)//converting the string into its binary equivalent
{
     int ac,i,j,l,chklen;
     String bc,en="";
     char ic;
     l = s.length();    
     for(i=0;i<l;i++)
     {   
         ic = s.charAt(i); //takes out every character
         bc = ""; 
         ac = (int)ic;  //ASCII value of this character
         while(ac!=0)
         {
             bc = Integer.toString((ac%2)) + bc; //converting the ASCII value into binary equivalent
             ac = ac/2;
         }
         chklen = bc.length();//length of the binary equivalent
         if(chklen<7)
         {
            for(j=1;j<=(7-chklen);j++) //increasing the length of binary equivalent so that it becomes equal to 7
            {  
                bc = "0" + bc;
            }
         }
         en = en+bc; //concatenating all the binary equivalent into one string
     }
     return (en);
}

String decode_find(String s)// converts binary(i.e. in the form of dots and space) to decimal
{
    int f;//for the index of every character of code
    long l,i,j,ac;
    char c;
    String de="";

    l = s.length();
    f = 0;//index of first caharcter
    for(i=0;i<(l/7);i++)//since the length of every binary equivalent of a character is 7 therefore there will be (length/7) characters in a code of length l
    {
        ac = 0;//intializes the decimal(ASCII) equivalent to zero
        for(j=6;j>=0;j--)//loop will work 7 times for every binary equivalent of a character
        {
            c = s.charAt(f);//takes out every dot or space
            if(c=='.')//it means that c corresponds to 'one'
            {
                ac = ac + ((int)Math.pow(2,j));//converting binary into decimal(ASCII) equivalent by adding all the powers of 2 which correspond to one('.') 
            }
            f++;//increasing the index for next character of binary equivalent
        }
        de = de + ((char)ac);//converts the ASCII equivalent into character and then concatenates it with the intitial string
    }
    return(de);
}

void encode_display(String en)//displays the code
{
    int i,l;
    char ic;
    System.out.println("YOUR ENCODED MESSAGE IS :");
    l=en.length();
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        ic=en.charAt(i);
        if(ic=='1')//for every 'one' it will print '.'(dot)
        {
             System.out.print(".");
        }
        else if(ic=='0')//for every 'zero' it will print ' '(space)
        {
             System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}

void decode_display(String de)
{
    System.out.println(de);
}

public static void main(String args[])throws IOException,InterruptedException
{
    BufferedReader obj = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    char ch;

    ed2 ed = new ed2();

    System.out.println("PRESS 'E' TO ENCODE A MESSAGE OR PRESS 'D' TO DECODE A MESSAGE");
    ch = (char)obj.read();

    if((ch=='e')||(ch=='E'))
    {
        ed.encode();
    }
    else if((ch=='d')||(ch=='D'))
    {
        ed.decode();
    }
}
```

}